# How to compile Python code with PyTesseract to EXE?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-tesseract

I have working Python project which use **pytesseract** library.
I tested it in PyCharm. Python ver. 3.7.
Now I'm trying to compile this project to exe using PyInstaller.

When I run exe I got error:

> File "getTextFromScreen.py", line 5, in  ModuleNotFoundError:
>
> No module named 'pytesseract' [9188] Failed to execute script main

My import in code looks like:

```
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'
```

I provide whole 'Tesseract-OCR' folder in python project folder and compiled project folder.

I don't know what do I do wrong.
I want to ask you for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using windows? You must include the .exe extension in your path. Instead just `r'Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'`, use `r'Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'`. I have a project using PyTesseract too, provide a whole tesseract folder in python project and working well after compiled using PyInstaller.

Comment: That fixed my issue. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an .exe and run it from any other pc where the Tesseract is not, you must use the auto-py-to-exe tool, in the additional files option attach the folder where all the Tesseract files were installed, then put this in your code

```
import sys

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    _path = os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, './tresseract/tesseract.exe')
    print(_path)
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd =_path
    # the .exe will look here
else:
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\tresseract\\tesseract.exe"
    #ruta donde se encuentre su tresseract
```

and compile, good luck !!